# REGEX for Repeated Punctuation X Number of Times

Tags: regex

Is there any way to do this:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6}.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6}.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6}
```

Without repeating the matching part for as many times as I'd like to match it for?

I tried `([^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6}){3}` but that didn't work.

Basically, I'm trying to catch when users text repeated punctuation too many times:

> Oh my goodness!!!!!!!!!  This is insane!!!!!!! What are you going to
>   do about this???!??!???!

But this is OK:

> Oh my goodness!!!!!!!!!  This is insane! What are you going to
>   do about this?

Comment: Can you clarify the exact requirements for a punctuation block being fine? Maybe provide some more examples of what passes and what doesn't.

Comment: You can at least shorten to `[^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6}(.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6}){2}`. It may be possible to make an own character class but this depends on the language you are using.

Comment: @L3viathan - I don't want any punctuation repeated more than 6 times in a block.
So [^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6} is EXACTLY what I want.  Although, I guess [^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6,} is more accurate.  But I only want to match when they have a block X times.  (I might do 3, I might do 15. Not sure yet. I'm also trying to stop users from entering ASCII art.)

Comment: Please tag a regex flavor.

Comment: @revo - I have no idea.  It's regex in chatbot software.

Comment: @LisaK Both your examples contain punctuation repeated more than 6 times in a block (the initial exclamation marks).

Comment: @L3viathan Yes, I know.  That was purposeful.  I want to match the 1st example but not the 2nd.

Comment: This works correctly: [^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6}.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6}.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6}
But I was wondering if there was an easier way to do it in case I decide that I want to allow more than 3 blocks of repeated punctuation.  If I wanted to allow 15 blocks, that regex would get pretty long.

Comment: What language that chatbot software is written in?

Comment: You say you "don't want any punctuation repeated more than 6 times in a block.", but it's purposeful that in the first example, which you want to match there is punctuation repeated more than 6 times in a block.

Answer (score 0):

YEs you can do it like this

`[^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6}(?:.*?[^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6}){number of times}`

readable

```
 [^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6} 
 (?:
      .*? 
      [^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6} 
 ){number of times}
```

You could set a range on `number of times` as well,
where `number of times` could be `1,10`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match any character from a class, and then more of that same character (e.g. clusters of identical punctuation), you can use capture groups:

```regex
([^A-Za-z0-9\s])\1{2,}
```

This matches `???`, `.......`, and `!!!!!!!`, but not `!??!!!?` or `...!..`. Depending on the regex dialect, you may need to use `$1` instead of `\1`.

#### Explanation:

```regex
 [^A-Za-z0-9\s]            # your character class
(              )           # make this part a capture group
                \1         # match whatever matched the first capture group
                  {2,}     # 2 or more times
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do what you want:

```
([^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6,}([\w\s]+|$)){2,}
```

It looks for a group of 6 or more symbol characters (`[^A-Za-z0-9\s]{6,}`), followed by one or more word/whitespace characters or the end of line (`([\w\s]+|$)`). The `{2,}` quantifier then requires that the group occurs at least twice.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tado8L/4)